# Apache 2.4.7 does not accept RSA ciphers but openssl does

Tags: apache-2.4, openssl, firefox, rsa

```
# apachectl -version
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 22 2014 14:36:38
```

I've got `ssl.conf` configured with the default `SSLCipherSuite` (`SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5`). I've also tested all sort of combinations.

I've checked the ciphers available on the host using `openssl ciphers`, and there are plenty of RSA ciphers.

Here are the dependencies of my mod_ssl.so:

```
 # locate mod_ssl.so
 /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so

 # ldd `locate mod_ssl.so`
 linux-vdso.so.1 => (0x00007fffb5dfe000)
 libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f915c0ba000)
 libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f915bce0000)
 [... omitted libpthread and libc ...]
```

Ldd on `/usr/bin/openssl` yields the same dependencies on libssl and libcrypto (v 1.0.0).

I cannot get a connection using the RSA cipher. I checked those using `openssl s_client -connect <server>:<port> -cipher 'ANY-RSA-CIPHER'`.

I also ran an analysis on https://www.ssllabs.com which confirms the openssl commands: only DSS is supported.

This is a problem as firefox 37 does not support DSS anymore, resulting in a ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap error.

Any idea?

Comment: What SSLCipherSuite lines have you tried, specifically?  Do you have additional SSLCipherSuite lines somewhere in your configuration that may be overriding what you're trying to set?

Comment: Using `openssl ciphers` will tell you what your `openssl` is capable of; but apache may not have been linked against the same libraries. Consider running `ldd` against `mod_ssl.so` and `openssl` and see if anything's missing. e.g.: my `mod_ssl.so` (FreeBSD) uses `libssl`, `libcrypt`, and `libcrypto`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers, I've updated the question, but I just found a good lead... I keep you posted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out : the private key was using DSA...

Kinda stupid!

I generated another private key & self-signed certificate using RSA and... voilà!

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 [...]
```